# Create Excel sheet from plist and also viceversa

Tags: ios

How to create a excel sheet from this plist file.Please find the attached image.

[image]

Comment: Post some code for what you have tried so far.

Comment: Could you please be more clear of the kind of mapping you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CSV parser. It is useful to convert plist in excel and vice versa.